# XML Parsing error: no root element found (empty content) Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django, firefox

I am using ajax to connect to a view in my web application.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'PATCH',
        success: function() {
          var d = new Date();
          img = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
          if (img.src.includes("?")){
            img.src = img.src.split("?")[0] + '?' + d.getTime();
          } else {
            img.src = img.src + '?' + d.getTime();
          }

        },
    });
```

When I click on the button that triggers this, everything works, but I get an `XML Parsing error`. According to the other questions on stack exchange, this might be beacuse of an empty content. When I use the firefox developer tools, the content of the `reverse` of the concerned view is indeed empty, because of which, I think, firefox interprets it as an xml.
My problem is, that I do not know how to fill the content. In my view, I changed `return Response(status=200)` to `return Response(status=200, content_type='image/jpeg')`, because the view does something to an image. But still the content seems to stay empty and I still get the error. I don't know how else to alter the content type than by specifying it in the response.
I only get this error in firefox, not in chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I only had to set the content_type to `text/html`...

Comment: The correct mime type for XML is `application/xml`, explicitly *not* `text/html`.

Answer (score 0):

The server response is missing header `Content-Type`. 
So the JavaScript 'success' handler cannot parse correctly the response body.